# How To setup epson ecotank printer in ubuntu without driver available from epson

Tags: epson

i got an ET-1810.

Just now figured out that there are no drivers from epsons side for linux available. So wanted to try ipp or raw to be able to use it over wifi. However, i have not figured out how to go. Any ideas? Each time i try generic drivers i just get wrong looking print results

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after playing a while i figured out that its possible to set it up via the cups tools which are available at: localhost:631 in the browser.Via the native ubuntu point and click tool i was not able to set it up. For those of us who are not so familiar with cups this [video about cups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=En2DJAMpwmY) is helpfull.

1. Install CUPS
2. Go to the localhost:631
3. Navigate: Administration -> Add printer
4. Choose: IPP as protocol
   [image]
5. Enter the address like this under connection `ipp://yourprinteriphere:631/ipp/print`
   [image]
6. Give the printer a name
   [image]
7. Choose EPSON under Make and press continue
   [image]
8. Select `IPP everywhere` and click "Add Printer"
   [image]
9. Confirm defaults
10. Under Maintenance choose the "Print test page"
    [image]

Hope that helps others.

Answer (score 1):

I went to epson site and got everything I need from there.
https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule

Hopefully it well help someone